# How to install previous version of Maven (3.0.4)?

Tags: apt, maven-3

The way my Maven packages are configured, something breaks when I have the latest version installed (I think 3.4).  On another computer, where I have 3.0.4, the build runs fine.  I am looking for a way to install a previous version using `apt-get`.  I followed [these instructions](http://java.dzone.com/articles/installing-maven-304-ubuntu) and they completed fine but when I ran `mvm -v`, I got the following error, so something must have been wrong with the tar ball:

[ERROR] Unknown lifecycle phase "–v"

Comment: Have you considered trying to fix the build in the current version of Maven? Also, the version of maven in the repos is 3.0.5.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Download and extract the installation package:

   ```
   cd /opt
   wget -O- https://archive.apache.org/dist/maven/maven-3/3.0.4/binaries/apache-maven-3.0.4-bin.tar.gz |
   sudo tar -xzv
   ```
2. Add `/opt/apache-maven-3.0.4/bin` to your `PATH`.

See also http://maven.apache.org/download.cgi.

Comment: update: link does not work.  Use this one instead: https://archive.apache.org/dist/maven/maven-3/3.0.5/binaries/apache-maven-3.0.5-bin.tar.gz

Comment: and remove the .gz in the 4th step

Comment: add /bin to the end of that path in step 9

Answer (score 2):

This is how I did it.

Download whatever maven build you want. (here 3.0.4)

Download your archived version from https://archive.apache.org/dist/maven/maven-3
(If you are a beginner, go to binaries then download the version with tar.gz extension under version you want. here **apache-maven-3.0.4-bin.tar.gz** is the file you want)

Then create a link using below command

```
sudo ln -s /home/menuka/software/apache-maven-3.2.5 /usr/bin/mvn
```

The first file path should be where you extract the maven from tar.gz second path is you don't need to change. Because it is the Linux way to create an executable link (http://www.linfo.org/usr_bin.html)

Now we have to set up environment variables for maven to work. Run below command with you favorite text editor. I here use beginner-friendly gedit.

```
sudo gedit /etc/profile.d/apache-maven.sh
```

Add below content to the editor (Make sure you replace your JAVA_HOME with your jdk path)

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-oracle
export M2_HOME=/usr/bin/mvn
export MAVEN_HOME=/usr/bin/mvn
export PATH=${M2_HOME}/bin:${PATH}
```

Save and exit the editor.

then run below command to update Linux configurations

```
 source /etc/profile.d/apache-maven.sh
```

now if you completed above process correctly below command give and output

```
mvn -version
```

[image: mvn -version output]

Answer (score 0):

You can Install maven 3.0.4 with [**ppa:rockclimb/netbeans**](https://launchpad.net/~rockclimb/+archive/netbeans/+index?field.series_filter=raring) repository.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:rockclimb/netbeans

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install maven
```

Comment: I am not sure whether this is a trustworthy way of installing Maven. Because this will work as long as 3.0.4 is the latest maven version on this repository. Then it will be next version